# unicode:characters_to_list seems doesn't work for utf8 list

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, erlang

I am trying to convert UTF-8 string to Unicode (code point) list with [Erlang library "unicode](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html). My input data is a string "АБВ" (Russian string, which correct Unicode representation is [1040,1041,1042]), encoded in UTF-8. When I am running following code:

```erlang
1> unicode:characters_to_list(<<208,144,208,145,208,146>>,utf8).
[1040,1041,1042]
```

it returns correct value, but following:

```erlang
2> unicode:characters_to_list([208,144,208,145,208,146],utf8).  
[208,144,208,145,208,146]
```

does not. Why does it happens? As I read in [specification](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/unicode.html#type-charlist), input data could be either binary or list of chars, so, as for me, I am doing everything right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of the function is `unicode:characters_to_list(Data, InEncoding)`, it expects `Data` to be either binary containing string encoded in `InEncoding` encoding or possibly deep list of characters (code points) and binaries in `InEncoding` encoding. It returns list of unicode characters. Characters in erlang are integers.

When you call `unicode:characters_to_list(<<208,144,208,145,208,146>>, utf8)` or `unicode:characters_to_list([1040,1041,1042], utf8)` it correctly decodes unicode string (yes, second is noop as long as `Data` is list of integers). But when you call `unicode:characters_to_list([208,144,208,145,208,146], utf8)` erlang thinks you pass list of 6 characters in `utf8` encoding, since it's already unicode the output will be exactly the same.

There is no `byte` type in erlang, but you assume that `unicode:characters_to_list/2` will accept `list of bytes` and will behave correctly.

To sum it up. There are two usual ways to represent string in erlang, they are bitstrings and lists of characters. `unicode:characters_to_list(Data, InEncoding)` takes string `Data` in one of these representations (or combination of them) in `InEncoding` encoding and converts it to list of unicode codepoints.

If you have list `[208,144,208,145,208,146]` like in your example you can convert it to binary using [`erlang:list_to_binary/1`](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#list_to_binary-1) and then pass it to `unicode:characters_to_list/2`, i.e.

```
1> unicode:characters_to_list(list_to_binary([208,144,208,145,208,146]), utf8).
[1040,1041,1042]
```

---

`unicode` module supports only unicode and latin-1. Thus, (since the function expects codepoints of unicode or latin-1) `characters_to_list` does not need to do anything with list in a case of flat list of codepoints. However, list may be deep (`unicode:characters_to_list([[1040],1041,<<1042/utf8>>]).`). That is a reason to support list datatype for `Data` argument.

Comment: Thanks, it sounds reasonable. But I have one question:) What is a point to make possible to pass lists in function characters_to_list, if in that case it doesn't do anything, and just thinks, that you pass a list of unicode characters?

Comment: @koluch String might be in other encoding (`InEncoding` parameter). It is noop only for unicode (and it's subsets). It thinks it's unicode because you pass `utf8` as `InEncoding` (converting list of unicode characters to list of unicode characters). I tried to stress it out in my answer, but I guess I failed. Not good enough in english :-(

Comment: No, it's not about your Endlish, I did understand you:) But, any possible combinations of `Data` and `InEncoding` will return the same thing! For example, if you call it as `("abc", latin1)`, it will return the same thing (because string in `latin1` is correct unicode string), and for another utf encoding it returns the same thing (for example, `unicode:characters_to_list(binary_to_list(<<"abc"/utf32>>),utf32)`). It it's not, could you, please, give an example combination of `Data` and `InEncoding`, when `characters_to_list` will return anything else, than `Data`

Comment: @koluch Hmm, I think you are probably right. However, there is still a reason to support it. I updated my answer. BTW, your example would fail anyway, you're making the same error as in your question, trying to call function with list of bytes.

Comment: If you check the function definition a bit more you will see that `Data` is a "a possibly deep list of integers and binaries" and the output is a "a list of integers representing Unicode characters". It is has a sort of built-in super "flatten" where the binaries are encoded and the list elements are the unicode values. There is a `characters_to_binary` which works in a similar fashion but the output is an encode binary.

Comment: @rvirding yes, thank you :-) I already found it and updated my answer.

Comment: Yes, but the functions not only take *either* a list or binary, they also take a *combination* of them.

Answer (score 2):

`<<208,144,208,145,208,146>>` is an UTF-8 binary.

`[208,144,208,145,208,146]` is a list of bytes (not code points).

`[1040,1041,1042]` is a list of code points.

You are passing a list of bytes, but the function wants a list of chars or a binary.

Comment: What the difference between list of bytes and list of chars? There is no "byte" type in erlang, and char is just an integer in interval 0..16#10ffff (http://www.erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/typespec.html). So, for me, [208,144,208,145,208,146] is a list of integers (and, in another words, list of chars)

Comment: @koluch In one sense there is no difference, Erlang doesn't have a character data type. It is all a matter of how they are interpreted, "byte" is 0..255 while "char" is 0..16#10ffff, a full unicode codepoint.

Comment: The same integer has different meaning as a byte and as a char.

Comment: Here is an example:
Code point 208 is "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER ETH" (and it is not what you want).
But in your case 208 is a part of the code point 1040 "CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER A", which can be encoded as <<208,144>> in UTF-8.